# Riverpod base class for WidgetRef and ProviderRef

Tags: flutter, riverpod

```dart
function(
  WidgetRef ref, 
  // ProviderRef ref,
) {
  final a = ref.read(aProvider);
  // Some logic
}
```

What base class that can read WidgetRef and ProviderRef?

Comment: There's a `Ref` class.

Comment: @Josteve could you make it as answer, I will tick it.

Comment: wait I have this error `The argument type 'WidgetRef' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Ref'`

Comment: Hi @Ryde, please share the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's been answered in here by the creator https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/discussions/1152

> However, I wondered why Ref and WidgetRef don't share a common
> interface?
>
> That's voluntary. The fact that you need a common interface shows a
> flaw in your architecture
>
> You most definitely did something wrong somewhere. You should never
> need to use WidgetRef outside of widgets

So, there is no base class or common interface. It's considered there is flaw in your code if you need WidgetRef outside of widgets.

*[Edit]*
Btw there is a way to share a function that works with both ref. By setting it parameters with notifier class (to change state), or just set the object (to read).

```dart
function(
  ANotifierClass noti, 
  AClass a,
) {
  noti.callSomething();
  // Do something with a
}
```

called like

```dart
// ref can be WidgetRef or Ref
function(
  ref.read(aProvider.notifier),
  ref.read(aProvider),
);
```